# Is it possible to create video file from BitmapDatas in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, encoding

Basically I'd like to know if there are any libraries out there that lets me create a video file in the flash runtime.  I know such a process would take a lot of resources, but I would still like to know if it was possible?

I would guess it could work like just passing it a bitmapdata for each frame.

Comment: What is your intent for the video? Are you looking to simply display BitmapData assets in rapid sequence, or do you want to write a video file to disk? In the former case, you don't really need a video file, you can simply use an ENTER_FRAME event listener or a timer to change the `bitmapData` property of a Bitmap object. In the latter case, you're going to need to write a custom encoder (or find an encoding library) that relies on ByteArray and will be a TON of work.

Comment: @Joshua Sullivan : I wanted to save the file to disk :) Maybe my questions wasn't clear enough, but the other thing is just too simple to ask for.

Answer (score 3):

Try [this](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/assets_code/SimpleFlvWriter.as.txt). Usage:

```
var myWriter:SimpleFlvWriter = SimpleFlvWriter.getInstance();
myWriter.createFile(myFile, 320,240, 30, 120);
myWriter.saveFrame( myBitmapData1 );
myWriter.saveFrame( myBitmapData2 );
myWriter.saveFrame( myBitmapData3 ); // etc.
myWriter.closeFile();
```

Comment: It is something like this I was looking for! The ability to save audio would also be really cool.